# Resolve this error I am getting in this SSIS Package?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

So I created an SSIS package that retrieves a dataset through a SQL query, then converts the data type, puts the data through a lookup so that only new records are inserted, and finally the lookup inserts the data into the destination database. However I am getting this error that I'm not understanding, where am I going wrong with this?

[image]

The error code attached below.

> [OLE DB Destination [42]] Error: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "The statement has been terminated.".
> An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 11.0"  Hresult: 0x80004005  Description: "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'pk_Lead_Transaction_ID'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'SF.Opportunity'. The duplicate key value is (211806634).".

Comment: You have a primary key violation. What does your data flow look like? How is the Lookup configured? If you run your source query `SELECT DISTINCT Primary_Transaction_ID, Transaction_STATUS FROM DB1.dbo.Table1 WHERE Primary_Transaction_ID = 211806634` for that duplicate key, do you get more than one result? i.e. (211806634, Status1), (211806634, Status2) ?

Comment: Either `SF.Opportunity` already has a record with PK value 211806634 and you are trying to insert another one, _or_ it doesn't and you are trying to insert more than one record with that value in your SSIS package. BTW if you are doing database work it's important that you understand what a primary key is.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I understand what a primary key is, my confusion stems from the fact that this insert shouldn't be possible due to the fact that the "Lookup" capability in SSIS is supposed to remove duplicate values and insert only new values. In my case here, it isn't doing that and throwing this error instead. So I'm unsure why the "Lookup" function isn't working as expected in this case.

Comment: I understand. It helps to add this context to your question. I suggest you inspect your data and work out which of the cases I've posed is actually happening here. Lookup certainly doesn't remove duplicates. It just looks something up. You might have subsequent logic that removes records based on that Personally I recommend an ELT approach where all of the work is done in staging tables in the database as I find building these kind of structures in SSIS to be poor performers, error prone and difficult to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid I fully agree, I'm actually switching over to doing this with the staging process right now. Just isn't worth it trying to do this in SSIS.

Comment: SSIS can be tough sometimes.  But, you can troubleshoot this.  You could configure error handling on your OLE DB Destination so bad rows are just discarded.  That way, everything that is fit to be inserted ... is.  Rows that violate your PK constraint will simply be discarded.  They exit out of the OLE DB destination component along the red line.  I'd recommend wiring up that red line to a throwaway component like a conditional split.  More reading about error handling here.  https://www.timmitchell.net/post/2019/09/30/using-ssis-error-output/

Comment: What does your lookup look like? Did you configure it to move "not matched" to another output instead of "fail component"?